# Erro por conta de função map retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, map

Pesquisei esse erro mas não consegui aplicar nada que funcionasse. Esse é meu map, ele mapeia um array de erros.

```
interface ErrorProps {
  errors: string[]
}

const ErrorMessage = ({ errors }: ErrorProps) => {
  const intl = useIntl()

  return (
    <>
      {errors.map((error: string, index: number) => {
        return (
          <Text sx={widgetStyles.messageError} key={index}>
            {intl.formatMessage({ id: error })}
          </Text>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

E aqui tem onde eu chamo ele.

```
{errorState && <ErrorMessage errors={props.rawErrors} />}
```

Esse errorState é pra ele nao printar o erro se nao tiver.

O erro:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não publique código ou mensagem de erros como imagem. Quem quiser o responder, terá que digitar caractere por caractere antes de testar o seu código e programadores com deficiência visual não conseguem ler o seu código pois seus dispositivos assistivos são incapazes de transformar imagens em texto.

Comment: obrigada pela dica, isso de acessibilidade realmente é muito importante. mas o ambiente aqui continua sendo nada acolhedor. precisamos redigir um tcc pra tirar uma duvida

Comment: E não precisa ser um TCC, basta ser um [mcve] <- leia este link e veja como melhorar a pergunta. Enfim, o problema é porque `errors` é undefined, então tem que ver de onde ele está vindo e porque está vindo undefined...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu problema é que o valor de `props.rawErrors` não é um `array`, esta vindo como `undefined`, recomendo que tente dar uma olhada pra tentar descobrir o motivo, mas com o exemplo de código que temos ai uma possível solução para o erro seria o seguinte:

```
{errorState && <ErrorMessage errors={props.rawErrors ?? []} />}
```

Dessa forma caso o valor de `props.rawErrors` seja `undefined` ele irá passar um `array` vazio, evitando o erro.

Comment: Isso funcionou sim. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @luca Em vez disso, talvez seja melhor tratar dentro do componente, ou seja, ele mesmo verifica se `errors` é undefined (e só chama `map` se não for). Senão todos os lugares que usam o componente terão que lembrar que precisam usar `??`. Sem contar que ao passar `[]` vc  acaba fazendo uma chamada desnecessária (pois nesse caso `map` vai retornar outro array vazio...)